# Adding Speech Recognition Hook to export const page in react to determine what word is said

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, speech-recognition

i am trying to add some speech recognition to my react app. If the user says a specific word - 'frog', it allows them to open the next page. However I am stuck in adding this line to my page, because it is a hook it isn't allowed:

```
const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition();
```

Is there a way to add it without creating a new component, as the button on this page needs to know what has been said and whether to allow the user to proceed.

Below  is my code:

```
export const AuthPage = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    //THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE HOOK ERROR
    // const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition();

const navigateToNextPage = () => {
    navigate(`/frogPage/${name}`);};

return (
    <main className='simple-wrapper'>
        <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Say Word</button>
        //ONLY SHOW NEXT BUTTON IF THEY SAID THE WORD FROG CORRECTLY
        {transcript.includes("frog") && (
        <button onClick={navigateToNextPage}>Next</button>)
    </main>
);
```

};

Comment: I believe the error is coming from your using useSpeechRecognition() and we would need to see it probably to determine what's happening.

Comment: @innocent what code would you like me to post? UseSpeechRecognition is an external library, but I will post whatever code would help

Comment: @innocent what error are you getting exactly?

Comment: @anaval Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Comment: @innocent but your `AuthPage` is a functional component no?

Comment: @anaval I believe this is asked by Helpimacoder needs help and I believe. Pardon, I have been busy I'll try to take a look at the issue. Helpimacoder  is the library you are using react-speech-recognition ?

Comment: @innocent yes that is the library

Comment: @anaval yes I think so

Comment: @Helpimacoder Can you add your full code to the question?

Answer (score 1):

judging from your feedback it looks like you are trying to use hooks inside a class component.

solution: create a wrapper component

```
function WrapperComponent({ renderChild }) {
 const result = useSpeechRecognition();
 return renderChild(result)
}


class MyComponent {
 render() {
  return <WrapperComponent
    renderChild={({ transcript, resetTranscript }) => (
      <main className='simple-wrapper'>
          <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Say Word</button>
          //ONLY SHOW NEXT BUTTON IF THEY SAID THE WORD FROG CORRECTLY
          {transcript.includes("frog") && (
          <button onClick={navigateToNextPage}>Next</button>)
      </main>
    )}
  />
 }
}
```

you may even use props.children(as a function) directly if you want. use whatever is comfortable.

Comment: How do I export this? Like in my original code - export const AuthPage = () => {

Comment: you use.
`export function .......`
`export class ......`

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So, I tried this out and the only thing giving error. I did encounter was with useNavigate for some reason. So, I switched to `react-router-dom@5.2.0` due to more familiarity.

Upon reading the NPM documentation for it ([doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition)). This might be dependent on your browser too. So, it does recommends adding polyfill to it but updated chrome should support this.(due to the Web Speech API)

I am using react-speech-recognition (3.9.0) and react version17.0.2. Also, the **react-speech-recognition library requires React 16.8 or greater for the React hooks to be used**

Below is the full code which worked for me

```
// AuthPage.js

import SpeechRecognition, {
  useSpeechRecognition
} from "react-speech-recognition";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory(); // usehistory in place of useNavigate 
  // const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { transcript, resetTranscript } = useSpeechRecognition();

  const navigateToNextPage = () => {
    console.log("This works");
    history.push("/homepage");
    // navigate(`/frogPage/${name}`);
  };

  return (
    <main className="simple-wrapper">
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Say Word</button>
      {/* //ONLY SHOW NEXT BUTTON IF THEY SAID THE WORD FROG CORRECTLY */}
      {transcript.includes("frog") && (
        <button onClick={navigateToNextPage}>Next</button>
      )}
    </main>
  );
};

export default AuthPage;
```

Just incase if you want to test it out yourself. The below is the App page I added which should work and should display the Say Word button and after  the speechrecognition by saying 'frog' it provides a way to navigate to the homepage.

```
// App.js
import React from "react";
import AuthPage from "./AuthPage";
import Homepage from "./Homepage";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

// const SpeechlySpeechRecognition = createSpeechlySpeechRecognition(appId);

// SpeechRecognition.applyPolyfill(SpeechRecognitionPolyfill);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>{/* <Dictaphone /> */}</div>

      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <AuthPage />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/homepage">
            <Homepage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
// Homepage.js
import React from "react";

const Homepage = (props) => {
  return <div>Homepage</div>;
};

export default Homepage;
```

Also, Link to the solution [working link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rhodes-jjx30l?file=/src/AuthPage.js:804-828) . Also, Keep in mind you need to allow your microphone on the webpage :)